# Displaying all the posts of user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get all posts that a user send. For example user: admin, it will show admin's posts. I write some code, but probably I made a mistake and I got an error. 
The error that I get:

```
AttributeError at /index_page/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'models'
```

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
def index_page(request):
    logged_in_user = request.models.author
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**post_list.html**

```
<div>
{% for post in posts %}

    Username: {{ post.author.username }}
    Post: {{ post.text }}

    <br>

{% endfor %}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well like the error already hints: what is `request.models.author` supposed to mean?

Comment: Moreover the variable `logged_in_user` is never used

Comment: logged_in_user = request.user

Answer (score 6):

The error already hints to the line:

```
    logged_in_user = request.models.author
```

A `request` object has *no* `models` attribute. It has a `.user` attribute that specifies the logged in user, so you can use:

```
    logged_in_user = request.user
```

There is another error: you use `Post.objects.filter(user=user)`, but there is no `user` variable either, there is a `logged_in_user` variable. So you can fix the view with:

```
def index_page(request):
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

**Extra notes**:

1. since you need a user, it makes sense to decorate the function with the [**`login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator); and
2. Since Django allows you to *change* the `User` model, it might be beneficial to use the [standard way to refer to the user model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model). If you later change your mind and implement another user model, the creating migrations will *automatically* let the relations refer to the new model.

The two comments above are not *strictly* necessary to let it work. But it is what I think are good practices when developing Django apps (although of course these can be a bit "opinion-based").

Comment: It works! I can understand my problem, now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your view, request object does not contain your models.The view should be like below,

```
def index_page(request):
    logged_in_user = request.user
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=logged_in_user)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering a little bit late , But may be it help someone later . you can use class-based views . In your case

**views.py :**

```html
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app_name/template_name.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user)
```

**and in your urls.py :**

```html
path('user/<str:username>', views.UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
```

and then in your template :

```html
{% block content%}
<h1> My files </h1>
       {% for post in posts %}

               



       {% endfor %}
          {% endblock %}
```